# How do I solve with NoSuchMethodError:EdgeNGramTokenFilter

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Now my schma.xml config is:

```
<fieldType name="text_exact_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
     <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="7"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="7"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>      
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But now I have a problem  like this when i add data to the solr,
   I defined the fieldType's analyzer with solr.StandardTokenizerFactory without any problem,but when the analyzer with solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory could get out the error like this.
   I have import the jar such as lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar,lucene-analyzers-3.5.0.jar etc.
   I think lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar has inculde the class EdgeNGramFilterFactory.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramTokenFilter.<init>(Lorg/apache/lucene/util/Version;Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory.create(EdgeNGramFilterFactory.java:52)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.EdgeNGramFilterFactory.create(EdgeNGramFilterFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain.createComponents(TokenizerChain.java:67)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.createComponents(AnalyzerWrapper.java:102)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:180)
        at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.tokenStream(Field.java:552)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:95)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:254)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:446)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1521)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:217)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:556)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:435)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:150)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBeans(SolrServer.java:93)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBeans(SolrServer.java:77)

Please help me, thanks a lot!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add apache-lucene-analyzers.jar , you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapacheluceneanalyzersjar.htm)

Comment: which place should I add the apache-lucene-analyzers.jar, In fact, I have add the lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar,lucene-analyzers-3.5.0.jar etc.

Comment: the class that is missing is there in this jar, add it same way as you have added other jars

Comment: it also have the error, i guess the lucene'version maybe not matched.

Comment: lucene-analyzers-3.5.0.jar, replace this jar with the updated version and give it a try

Comment: Sorry,in fact,i use the lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.0.jar and lucene-core-4.5.0.jar

Comment: You have clue-0.0.1.jar included??

Comment: yes,i have included.I had check the source,it really missed the methed init().

Comment: but when i use the LowerCaseFilterFactory, it won't have any problem

Comment: lucene-analyzers-common-4.4.0.jar, try this version instead of 4.5.0 and try , it may solve the problem i think

Comment: Thanks a lot,I had solved the problem,the reason is importing the  lower version of lucene-analyzers.jar,i don't found that,the problem is disappered when i removed the lower jar.